# Android Screen Frozen

Tags: android

Every so often (and through no obvious reproduction steps) the device will get into a state where the screen will completely seize.  By 'seize' I mean that absolutely nothing will draw.  The behavior is much as if we had a blocking call on the main thread, but I have been able to catch the behavior while on the debugger and have confirmed that this is not the issue (not to mention we don't receive an ANR from Android).

To compound the confusion, I noticed that the app behaves normally through our logging statements when I interact with the screen.  So when I make a scrolling gesture, I'm able to see us inflating views, the appropriate network calls being made, &c.  The app is fully functional except the screen is not drawing anything.

Using the UI XML snapshot tool in Eclipse even shows that the views that *should* be on the screen are present (though the drawn image is the still the frozen 'screenshot').

I will note that we have recently introduced animations and specifically are using the nineoldandroids project to help us backport some of the functionality.  The problem seems to occur on all phones (including my 4.2.2 Galaxy Nexus), but, again, reproduction is difficult.

We're completely at a loss to explain this behavior and would appreciate any insight into what's causing and/or how to fix this issue!

**Edit:** After lots of testing today, it seems that draw(...) is not being called on any views.  This would explain why the screen is 'frozen'.  Measure *is* called (which explains why the UI XML snapshot correctly shows what *should* be on screen).

Answer (score 2):

We've figured out what went wrong, and hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Though we're still not sure exactly *how*, our app can get into a state where an onPreDraw listener is registered, but never unregistered.  Further, there was a state inside **that** onPreDraw listener that would cause it to return false. So when Android is going through all the onPreDraw listeners to ensure that it could draw, this listener that we no longer had a reference to was continually returning false.  Eliminating that condition seems to have solved our problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having the same problem too, now I know where to look for.

Comment: Nearly nine years later, this was the only question mentioning the issue my team was encountering. Eternal +1 for your completeness.